# Flex/actionscript 3 equivalents for __FILE__ and __LINE__

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm quite new to flex/actionscript and I was wondering if there is an equivalent for php's (and other languages) **FILE** and **LINE** identifiers?

Basicly I want to do some custom error logging and would like to something like:

```
 var mymessage:String = 'Oops, a hiccup occured at ' + __FILE__ + ', line: ' + __LINE__;
```

Where file and line would ofcourse be substituted for their values at compile time.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not directly possible, but there's a fairly usable workaround for personal testing

```
var stackTrace:String = new Error().getStackTrace();
if (stackTrace) {
    var mymessage:String = "Oops, a hiccup occurred " + stackTrace.split("\n")[1];
}
```

Adjust your abuse of `getStackTrace` to taste.

Comment: ...not directly possible... :( I was afraid that would be the case, since google didn't come up with anything. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @Douwe: stackTrace works in non-debug versions, it will give you class and method names, but not line number. Method name hopefully will be enough to trace it down, if you have 100+ line methods then that's a separate problem :)

Comment: I thought that was the case, but the docs said it returns `null` and I didn't have time to confirm/deny. Thanks for the heads up davr.

Comment: I'm gonna test that Davr, thanks. The main reason I was after filenames and linenumbers is that the centralized logging app we already use for other apps takes them as input, so I wanted them for completion and for not having to redo parts of the logging app.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Cory's answer to the above. First add:

```
-define=CONFIG::debugging,true
```

to your library's compiler settings (next to the "-locale en_US" in "Additional Compiler Arguments"). Then use this quickie library:

```
package ddd
{
  public class Stack
  {
    protected static function str(val:*):String
    {
      if( val == null      ) return "<null>";
      if( val == undefined ) return "<undefined>";
      return val.toString();
    }

    protected static var removeAt :RegExp = /^\s*at\s*/i;
    protected static var matchFile:RegExp = /[(][)][\[][^:]*?:[0-9]+[\]]\s*$/i;
    protected static var trimFile :RegExp = /[()\[\]\s]*/ig;

    /* Must maintain number of stack levels, so that _stack can assume the 4th line of getStackTrace */
    private static function _stack( msg:String="", ...params ):String
    {
      var s   :String = new Error().getStackTrace();
      var func:String = "??";
      var file:String = "??";
      var args:String = null;
      if(s)
      {
        func = s.split("\n")[4];
        func = func.replace( removeAt, "" );
        var farr:Array  = func.match( matchFile );
        if( farr != null && farr.length > 0 ) file = farr[0].replace( trimFile, "" );
        func = func.replace( matchFile, "" );
      }
      for each( var param:* in params )
      {
        args = ( args == null ? "" : args.concat(",") );
        args = args.concat( str(param) );
      }
      return func + "(" + (args==null?"":args) + ")" + ( (msg!=null && msg!="") ? ":"+msg : "" ) + " at " + file;
    }

    /* Must maintain number of stack levels, so that _stack can assume the 4th line of getStackTrace */
    public static function stack( msg:String="", ...params ):String
    {
      params.unshift( msg );
      return _stack.apply( null, params );
    }

    /* Must maintain number of stack levels, so that _stack can assume the 4th line of getStackTrace */
    public static function pstack( msg:String="", ...params ):void
    {
      CONFIG::debugging {
        params.unshift(msg);
        trace( _stack.apply( null, params ) );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then you can just call:

```
Stack.pstack();
```

inside any function to print the stack location at that point, which looks like this:

```
package::classname/function() at /wherever/src/package/classname.mxml:999
```

Just remember to turn debugging to false before compiling for production, and all that will be left is an empty pstack call that does nothing - the guts will be conditional-compiled out.

Comment: anything beyond this, like "logging levels", and you're making your own logging interface, which in my experience is a huge rabbit hole that rarely pays off in time spent. use the standard stuff that comes with the system. i just like this because the call is so small and stupid that you can put it in one-liner functions without making them scroll far off the right.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the line or file doesn't add to much information in Flex. I usually output class and method name and as my methods tend to be short, it usually is clear where something occurred.

If you find yourself with methods that are hundreds of lines long, you should rethink your coding style.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea.  Can you post code?  Ideally something like: `var msg:String = thisclassname + "." + thismethodname + ": an error message";`  Or do you mean you manually type each class name and method name?